# How can I temporarily run a resource intensive process without overheating my CPU?

Tags: temperature

I have a 2015 Macbook Pro with 2.5 GHz, 16GB.

I'm trying to run someone's deep learning python script on my macbook. The program has to take in training data and process it. It maxes out my CPU. I ran the fans on max speed and it got part way through the process but because my CPU cores were hitting 90 degrees I had to quit the script early.

Comment: Why did you have to quit - did the mac crash?

Comment: @Mark no it had been going on for about 10 minutes and I didnt want the computer to overheat (even at max fans)

Comment: The CPU is designed for 100°C run temps. Probably not an issue, see linked question for options to throttle anyways.

Answer (score -1):

make sure you have smc installed so you can adjust your fans...also, make sure your fans are clear of dust/debris...dust can create a real problem. you can also do new thermal paste but it may void your warranty...and thats only really necessary if youve got a constant, major overheating issue

Comment: Hey new user! Yeah I'm using the Macs Fan Control app and it's a relatively new computer so not much dust yet. I had lots of dust problems with my old laptop too.